# Getting values from dynamic controls in flex3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, dynamic, controls, flex3

I'm new in Flex 3 and ActionScript.
I would like to know how do I get the value of the dynamic textboxes via their id.

```
for (var countz:int = 0; countz < questionCount; countz++)          
{
  hboxtextboxz = new HBox();
  txt = new TextInput();
  txt.id = countz + "";
  hboxtextboxz.addChild(txt);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how I get the values out of the dynamic textboxes I created with the for loop?

Comment: please, put your code sample inside <pre><code> </pre></code> tags for better readability

Comment: Where are u adding the `hboxtextboxz` to the stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically get all the children of a Container, use the `getChildren()` method. It will return an Array of `UIComponent`s, If they are `TextInput` instances, cast them and get the value using the `text` property.

Sample code to get all the textBoxes from a container which are inside HBoxes.

```
var children:ArrayCollection = textBoxContainer.getChildren();
for(var i:int = 0; i < children.length; i++)
{
    var hbox:HBox = HBox(children[i]);
    var textBox:TextInput = TextInput( hbox.getChildAt(0));
    if(textBox != null)
    {
        trace(textBox.text);
    }
}
```

The above code is provided your UI structure is as :

```
<VBox id="textBoxContainer">
    <HBox>
         <TextInput/>
    </HBox>
     ....
</VBox>
```

Comment: Hey.. thanks for the informative reply. but may i know if i have multiple "hboxtextboxz" as parent. how can i get all the textboxes in all the "hboxtextboxz" that i have created in the loop.

Comment: i have updated the code, see if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a million!.That was what iam looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

By values do you mean the text inside of the box?

If you want to access it inside of your for loop just use the variable name:

txt.text

Otherwise if you create your text box in MXML you can set its id parameter and access it using that:
(text fields id).text

should give you the text that has been inserted into that box.